# Confusion about object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm practicing object oriented syntax in javascript and am having some problems. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function Name(first,mid,last) {
               this.first = first;
               this.middle = mid;
               this.last = last;
          }
          Name.prototype.fullname = function () {
               return this.first + " " + this.middle + " " + this.last;
          }
          Name.prototype.fullnamereversed = function() {
               return this.last + " " + this.middle + " " + this.first;
          }
          var s = new Name("James","Harlow","Smith")
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          document.body.innerHTML = s.fullname;
          document.body.innerHTML = s.fullnamereversed;
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, the innerHTML of the body is the exact text of Name.protoype ("function ()... this.first + this.middle + this.last..."). What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the functions with the () operator:

```
document.body.innerHtml = s.fullname();
```

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a function to the prototype, therefore you need to call it as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.innerHTML = s.fullname() + ' ' + s.fullnamereversed();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke your function: `document.body.innerHTML = s.fullname();`

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zRNBh/).

Answer (score 2):

`document.body.innerHTML = s.fullname;` sets the innerHTML to the function `s.fullname`.

If you want to set the innerHTML to what the function *returns*, then you need to actually call the function:

```
document.body.innerHTML = s.fullname();
```